# JUnit 5 AfterEach method calling before test method finished

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have test method that looks like:

```
@Test
test_testName()
{
   startSomeWorkInParallel();
   // waiting with await() static method and some timeout
   waitUntilActionFinishedOrFailAssert(timeout);
   checkResults();
}
```

Parallel work uses closeable resource to controll lifecycle and this resourse is closing in `@AfterEach` method:

```
@AfterEach
void afterEach()
{
    resource.close();
}
```

The problem is: `afterEach()` method is calling before `test_testName()` finished work and before waiting timeout expired.

How is it possible? And how can i solve it?

Comment: I think, the problem in your method:  waitUntilActionFinishedOrFailAssert(timeout);
Can you provide the code of this method?

Comment: When i replaced this method with Thread.sleep() i had the same problem: afterEach() is calling while test thread is waiting

Comment: Sounds to me like your wait-method is not waiting until ***workInParallel method is done. To check this you could simply add some log-statements around these methods to see exactly where your problem is.

Comment: @ElmarBrauch, i am sure that wait-method is waiting and always reacheable before workInParallel is done (i checked this with logger and debug). I am also sure that problem is as i said: afterEach() is calling while test thread is waiting. But idk how is it possible :(

Comment: Ok, in this case, the problem could be in your method: startSomeWorkInParallel(); Maybe you run the test logic in a different thread and don't wait for the end of this thread actually. Anyway. I need more information and still the code sample of these methods.

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo, you are right. This was because of error in waiting method (i waited for file and passed wrong directory to file constructor). Thank you so match!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original problem with the waiting method:

```
 waitUntilActionFinishedOrFailAssert(timeout);
```

It's not a problem with JUnit. Fixing this method solves the problem of sequentially executing the `afterEach()` method.